# How to avoid hard-coded, chained asynchronous functions in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Almost all of the functions in my program have some sort of asynchronous call, but they all rely on some previous function's results. Because of that, I've hard-coded the next function call into each individual one as such:

```
function getStuff() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(results) {
            // other functions involving results
            getMoreStuff(results);
        }
    });
}

function getMoreStuff(results) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(moreResults) {
            // other functions involving moreResults
            doSomethingWithStuff(moreResults);
        }
    );
}
```

And so on. It's a large chain where each function calls the next. While this works within the program, it makes each function useless individually.

I'm a bit lost on how to avoid this problem. I couldn't figure out how to use general callback functions, because when I make the function calls, it ends up like this (using the functions above):

```
getStuff(function() {
    getMoreStuff(results, doSomethingWithStuff);
};
```

But then 'results' hasn't been defined yet.

The solution seems obvious, I'm just being a bit dense about it. Sorry!

Comment: Pass callbacks as an extra parameter to your functions. The calling function can then decide what to do on completion. Your callback example just needs a parameter passed back. i.e. `getStuff(function(results) { getMoreStuff(results, function(results){doSomethingWithStuff(results);});};`

Comment: `getStuff(function(results)...` now results is defined.

Comment: @ Jay: I've added a full ajax example using `Deferred` and `Promise` to my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Overview

You have a couple of choices. You can have your code using those functions look like this, using callbacks:

```
getStuff(function(results) {
    getMoreStuff(results, doSomethingWithStuff);
});
```

or like this, using jQuery's `Deferred` and `Promise` objects:

```
getStuff().then(getMoreStuff).then(doSomethingWithStuff):
```

#### Using callbacks

Have both `getStuff` and `getMoreStuff` accept an argument that is a callback to call when they're done, e.g.:

```
function getStuff(callback) {
//                ^------------------------------ callback argument
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(results) {
            // other functions involving results
            callback(results);
//          ^------------------------------------ use the callback arg
        }
    });
}
```

...and similarly for `getMoreStuff`.

#### Using `Deferred` and `Promise`

jQuery's `ajax` function integrates with its `Deferred` and `Promise` features. You can just add `return` to your existing functions to make that work, e.g.:

```
function getStuff(callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}
```

*(Note: No need for the `success` callback.)*

Then this code:

```
getStuff().then(getMoreStuff).then(doSomethingWithStuff);
```

does this:

1. `getStuff` starts its `ajax` call and returns the `Promise` that call creates.
2. When that `ajax` call completes and resolves the promise, `getMoreStuff` is called with the results of the `ajax` call as its first argument. It starts *its* `ajax` call.
3. When `getMoreStuff`'s `ajax` call completes, `doSomethingWithStuff` is called with the results of *that* call (the one in `getMoreStuff`).

It's important to use `then`, not `done`, in order to get the correct results passed on at each stage. (If you use `done`, both `getMoreStuff` **and** `doSomethingWithStuff` will see the results of `getStuff`'s `ajax` call.)

Here's a full example using `ajax`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZjpZ/) | [Alternate Fiddle with the `ajax` calls taking one second each](http://jsfiddle.net/rZjpZ/2/) (makes it easier to see what's happening)

```
function getStuff() {
    display("getStuff starting ajax")
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {json: '{"message": "data from first request"}'},
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

function getMoreStuff(results) {
    display("getMoreStuff got " + results.message + ", starting ajax");
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {json: '{"message": "data from second request"}'},
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

function doSomethingWithStuff(results) {
    display("doSomethingWithStuff got " + results.message);
}

getStuff().then(getMoreStuff).then(doSomethingWithStuff);

function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Output:

```
getStuff starting ajax

getMoreStuff got data from first request, starting ajax

doSomethingWithStuff got data from second request
```

You don't need to be using `ajax` to get the benefit of this, you can use your own  `Deferred` and `Promise` objects, which lets you write chains like this:

```
one().then(two).then(three);
```

...for any situation where you may have asynchronous completions.

Here's a non-`ajax` example:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaMAJ/)

```
function one() {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    display("one running");
    setTimeout(function() {
      display("one resolving");
      d.resolve("one");
    }, 1000);
    return d.promise();
}

function two(arg) {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    display("Two: Got '" + arg + "'");
    setTimeout(function() {
      display("two resolving");
      d.resolve("two");
    }, 500);
    return d.promise();
}

function three(arg) {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    display("Three: Got '" + arg + "'");
    setTimeout(function() {
      display("three resolving");
      d.resolve("three");
    }, 500);
    return d.promise();
}

one().then(two).then(three);

function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Output:

```
one running

one resolving

Two: Got 'one'

two resolving

Three: Got 'two'

three resolving
```

These two (the `ajax` example and the non-`ajax` example) can be combined when necessary. For instance, if we take `getStuff` from the `ajax` example and we decide we have to do some processing on the data before we hand it off to `getMoreStuff`, we'd change it like this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZjpZ/3/)

```
function getStuff() {
    // Create our own Deferred
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    display("getStuff starting ajax")
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {json: '{"message": "data from first request"}', delay: 1},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            // Modify the data
            data.message = "MODIFIED " + data.message;

            // Resolve with the modified data
            d.resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return d;
}
```

Note that how we use that didn't change:

```
getStuff().then(getMoreStuff).then(doSomethingWithStuff);
```

All that changed was within `getStuff`.

This is one of the great things about the whole "promise" concept (which isn't at all specific to jQuery, but jQuery gives us handy versions to use), it's fantastic for decoupling things.

Comment: This chains the functions but does not pass the results caught by the async functions.

Comment: @Zim84: When a function passed into `then` returns a promise, the following functions end up depending on that promise, and any arguments given to `resolve` end up going to that subsequent function. This works with `ajax`, and with your own functions returning promises. See examples above. So with `one().then(two).then(three)`, where `one` and `two` return promises and resolve them later, `two` sees the arguments passed to `resolve` by `one`, and `three` sees the arguments passed into `resolve` by `two`.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! So `Deferred` and `Promise` would not work if you needed to process the ajax results before sending it to the next callback function? That is, you're giving a modified version of the results, rather than the results themselves?

Comment: @Jay: You're welcome. You can mix the two examples above, and do exactly that. :-) I've posted a third example to the end that has `getStuff` doing something to the data it receives prior to passing it on.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
function getStuff() {
    return $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(results) {
            // other functions involving results
        }
    });
}

function getMoreStuff(results) {
    return $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(moreResults) {
            // other functions involving moreResults
        }
    );
}
```

Then

```
getStufff().done(function(){
    getMoreStuff().done(doSomethingWithStuff)
})
```

etc

Comment: Exactly how is this passing the required result parameters to the next calls?

Comment: @HiTechMagic in both the said cases the parameters are the same as the ajax response data.. so as far as I can see there are no processed values passed to the chained function calls... if there are any processed results then either a classic callback parameter can be accepted or we can create a deffered object of our own

Comment: Gotcha... You chained the Ajax results. Cute. I assumed more processing may take place (and was left out of the example). otherwise why bother passing it in the first place :)

Comment: Shouldn't the chain go from getStuff() to doSomethingWithStuff() all the way? It seems to me your example does only one step chain. Best would be to do something like @HiTech below only with deferreds as you propose.

Comment: @HiTechMagic Yes, there would be more processing taking place, and those processed results would then be fed into the callback function. Really sorry I didn't specify that in my original question. I'll leave the question alone though, so the current answers make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Pass callbacks that accept a parameter:

```
function getStuff( callback ) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(results) {
            // callback with result
            callback(results);
        }
    });
}

function getMoreStuff(results, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(moreResults) {
            // callback with result
            callback(moreResults);
        }
    );
}

function doSomethingWithStuff(results, callback) {
    // process results via some means not described herein :)
    if (callback){
        // callback yet again with results, but only if callback provided this time
        callback(stillMoreResults);
    }
}
```

Then use with something like:

```
getStuff(function(results) { 
    getMoreStuff(results, function(moreresults){
             doSomethingWithStuff(moreresults);
        });
    };
```

This pattern is generally useful for any async operations. It is not specific to Ajax calls (I used it to create a complete animated board game in JQuery).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple. You have to use `Publish–subscribe` pattern.
The easiest implementation with jQuery:

```
$('body').trigger('joined-game', [game_id, response]);
```

First argument is the event name which you're publishing, second argument is the data array.

The best practise is to trigger event on the most specific DOM element, but if you subscribe the same event on multiple pages, and aren't sure if DOM element is present on all pages you can trigger it on `body` or some "dump/synthetic" not visible DOM element always present on all pages.

```
$("body").on('joined-game', function(event, game_id, response){
    //...
});
```

Then you subscribe event you want to utilize. Remember that besides your data, first argument is always event.

Another advantage of this solution is that you can split your code to several files.

More details: http://webility.pl/en/blog/entry/chaining-javascript-functions-without-dependecy-hell